# How to disable the authentication prompt from DVD mount and eject (16.04)

Tags: mount, dvd, authentication

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.  There is a prompt for authentication to mount or eject a DVD that is inserted.

Originally the user was a normal user.  I used System Settings to set the user as an administrator in hopes to stop the prompt.  It still prompts for authentication for those actions.

I would like to remove this prompt so that non administrators account can also use the DVD's without having sudo access.

Comment: Can you have a look at which groups you belong to? The command `groups` as an ordinary user  should show this. On my system this shows: `andrew adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxsf`, my suspicion is that you will be missing a few of these....

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks.  Adding the user to those groups resolved the issue.  I was also able to remove the user from sudoer.  If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept the answer so that others can benefit from a question resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user does not have access to the correct groups which on a clean Xenial Xerus installation looks like the following on *my* system:

```
andrew@athens:~$ groups
andrew adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxsf
```

You can safely ignore both `andrew` and `vboxfs` which relate to my own username and VirtualBox Filesystem membership respectively. You can carefully add your $USER to the required groups in `/etc/group` using `sudo` and your favorite commandline text editor or `gksudo` and your favourite gui text editor...